# Modifiy RTF template in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, rtf

I have a SQL Server database with a table that has a column that accommodates a  RTF template.

I was able to export the data as plain text to be able to edit the text of the  RTF template using an editor like LibreOffice.

BUT I can't import back the modified RTF template back to the database (as a plain text)

BULK insert form a text file is failed all the time ..

Any idea how to handle a complicated text file like RTF to be able to insert it back to the database?

Comment: Can you narrow the question to something like: "I can't do bulk insert from a file. I use following parameters and get following error."

Answer (score 0):

Using DUMP I was able to figure how SQL  export  the current  RTF value into  a query , unlike regular EXPORT to file ...
using DIFF  , I compared the modified RTF file and  the DUMP query , 
and changed  the RTF "code" so it will be in the right format to be inserted back to the table using simple UPDATE  clause